# What is the equivalent of cf enable-service-access cli command in cloud controller API

Tags: cloud-foundry

We are trying to programatically do the following in a sequence using cloud controller api

1. create a CF org
2. create a space under that org
3. enable a service to the org
4. create service instance and keys for that service

I am not sure what is the equivalent Cloud Controller API to the cli command cf enable-service-access

Can someone help with this

Answer (score 1):

Service are enabled and disabled per plan, and at the organization level - not for individual users.

All of the CF API calls are [pretty well documented](http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/). The API call you are looking for is [Creating a Service Plan Visibility](http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/1.24.0/service_plan_visibilities/creating_a_service_plan_visibility.html), and looks like this:

```
curl "https://api.[your-domain.com]/v2/service_plan_visibilities" -d '{
  "service_plan_guid": "ab5780a9-ac8e-4412-9496-4512e865011a",
  "organization_guid": "55d0ff39-dac9-431f-ba6d-83f37381f1c3"
}' -X POST \
    -H "Authorization: bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoidWFhLWlkLTE2NiIsImVtYWlsIjoiZW1haWwtMTIxQHNvbWVkb21haW4uY29tIiwic2NvcGUiOlsiY2xvdWRfY29udHJvbGxlci5hZG1pbiJdLCJhdWQiOlsiY2xvdWRfY29udHJvbGxlciJdLCJleHAiOjE0NjYwMDg4OTF9.ekbGeGWE6KvbEBH-IcvRj1f5j2yonbeKQqq2M8vMjvA" \
    -H "Host: example.org" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Cookie: "
```

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for the response, This command allows us to view the enabled services for an org. What I am looking for is how to enable a service to an org with Cloud Controller API. I have edited my initial question to re-word "sub-account" to "org". Hope my question is clear now.

Comment: No, the above example `curl` command to `/v2/service_plan_visibilities` with the `POST` method will modify service visibility, as you were asking about. A `GET` method to that endpoint would retrieve plan visibilities.